# How do I return the result of Ember.RSVP.all from a function?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The function below needs to return a true or false. Inside the `then` call at the bottom of the function, I get the value I need from `result.isAny('hasOverride')` but I don't know how to return this value from the `hasRoomUpcharge` function. How do I do this? I thought adding `return` in front of `Ember.RSVP.all` would do it, but it doesn't work. Please help!

```
hasRoomUpcharge: function(roomRates, defaultRoomTypeCode){
    var defaultRoomRates = roomRates.findBy('roomTypeCode', defaultRoomTypeCode);
    var nonDefaultRoomRates = roomRates.rejectBy('roomTypeCode', defaultRoomTypeCode);
    var nonDefaultRoomMasters = this.modelFor('propertyPricing').roomTypeMasters.rejectBy('isDefault');

    var promises = [];
    var promise;

        nonDefaultRoomMasters.forEach(function(roomMaster){
            var roomTypeCode = roomMaster.get('roomTypeCode');

             promise = roomMaster.get('roomRateUpcharge').then(function(roomRateUpcharge){
                var currentRoomMasterOnePersonPrice = nonDefaultRoomRates.findBy('roomTypeCode', roomTypeCode).onePersonPrice;
                var defaultRoomMasterOnePersonPrice = defaultRoomRates.onePersonPrice;
                var roomUpcharge = roomRateUpcharge.get('onePersonRateUpcharge');

                if(currentRoomMasterOnePersonPrice != defaultRoomMasterOnePersonPrice + roomUpcharge){
                    return { hasOverride: true };
                }
                else {
                    return { hasOverride: false };
                }
            });

            promises.push(promise);
        });


        return Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(result){
            return result.isAny('hasOverride');
        });
},
```

Comment: Could you create a JSBin showing the issue? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return the result from the `hasRoomUpcharge` function, as it returns *before* promises resolve (i.e. before the result is even known).

You are in fact doing it the right way - returning a promise from the `hasRoomUpcharge` function. When invoking this function, you should consume the returned promise, e.g.

```
this.hasRoomUpcharge(1, 3).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); //do something with the result
}
```